# HRESULT: 0x88980406 on ShowDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

Good Afternoon,
At my company, we have an application (portal) which opens up my application form in a new dialog. I can open up items upto 15 times before I get the following exception on 16th item (every time)

```
form.ShowDialog();
```

Here are the exception details.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught
>   Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x88980406 Source=PresentationCore
>   ErrorCode=-2003303418 StackTrace: at
>   System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel.SyncFlush() at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.CompleteRender() at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize() at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr
>   wparam, IntPtr lparam) at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate
>   catchHandler) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback,
>   Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean
>   isSingleParameter) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, Delegate method, Object arg) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr
>   wParam, IntPtr lParam) at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32
>   nCmdShow) at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox) at
>   System.Windows.Window.Show() at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog() at
>   MyProject.App.Main() in c:\Projects\MyProject\App.xaml.cs:line xxx
>   InnerException:

Other notes:
If I add the following line after showdialog()

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
```

Then after I close lets say 2 items, I can open 2 more, but it can never exceed more then 15 dialogs at any given point.

Here are details from task mngr when I have upto 15 items open.
Memory: Around 280k
Threads: 54
Handles 2,248,
User Objects: 700ish
GDI objects: 372.

After googling around, some similar problems were about having transparency or outdated drivers, I have also set transparency as false and updated all drivers. Some also suggested to update to latest .net framework (4.5) but I cant change that at this point from 3.5.

In my forms, I do have an imagectrl as well as a webbrowser, but I dispose them on close.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running the portal in debug? (With the hope that this gives you better error messages)

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480028/0x88980406-syncflush-is-there-a-workaround

Comment: Sayse, unfortunately I cant debug the portal (dont have code or pdb). I dont think i am pressing memory or hardware limit, I have 8gb ram and have around 50% free when i have 15 items often.

Comment: @sylar - Your programs memory allowance is different to the amount of ram you have. Without being able to debug the portal its going to be pretty hard to fix this, possibly not even your job to fix it?

Comment: @Sayse, are there any common config parameters where you can set memory limit? I can maybe check that out. Other then that I have notified portal folks and was told that something is up with my project and not portal since they cant reproduce it.

Comment: 700 USER Objects is quite excessive for WPF app.  Use a memory profiler to find your leak.

Comment: I think this points to things not getting garbage collected. One would every time you close the dialog, all the items (controls, objects and resources) being used within that dialog would be disposed off. That should be your stating point. Note if you have managed DLL you should be able to translate that to code using tools like dotpeek etc.